# Convert a given integer to another in minimum steps

Tags: c++, algorithm, pseudocode

Given two numbers A and B of equal number of digits. Find the minimum number of steps to convert A to B by increasing or decreasing a single digit in A in every step.
For example:  If A = 133 and B = 343, a possible solution is 133 -> 233 -> 333 -> 343. Minimum number of steps required is 3.

I tried a brute force approach. Here is my pseudo code

```
  while(a!=b)
  {
   if(a<b)
      {
        find (b-a)
        count number of digits in (b-a) keep it as n
        add the power(10,n) to a
        moves++;
       }
     else{
       find (a-b)
        count number of digits in (a-b) keep it as n
        subtract the power(10,n) from a
        moves++;
        }

  }
```

I was not able to get the correct answer on all test cases. Please suggest an efficient way to do this.

Comment: What cases don't work? Your algorithm seems legit. I would also consider converting the inputs to strings and go from there. It might actually turn out to be more efficient then doing all this math work.

Answer (score 6):

The solution to your problem would be

1. Traverse through a and b digit by digit, add the absolute value of the difference to a variable sum
2. sum would represent the number of digits needed to be changed
3. Time complexity O(number of digits)

```js
function solve(a, b){
    let sum = 0;
    while(a>0 && b>0){
        sum += Math.abs((a%10)-(b%10));
        a = Math.floor(a/10);
        b= Math.floor(b/10);
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(solve(133, 343));
console.log(solve(1234, 1221));
```

Comment: Can you provide any example?

Comment: added an example in javascript

Comment: I don't think the OP asked for the min number of moves, but rather the steps to get from a to b.

Comment: @K.Kirsz it is the minimum number of steps to convert from a to b

Answer (score 0):

Based on ideas from @K. Kirsz comment and @marvel308 answer, you can solve this problem via `std::valarray`, which is kind of an obscure standard container that does it's job here. You can run it [here](https://ideone.com/QkQyTT).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <string>

int solve(int a, int b)
{
    std::valarray<char> va(std::to_string(a).data(), std::to_string(a).length());
    std::valarray<char> vb(std::to_string(b).data(), std::to_string(b).length());

    return (std::abs(va - vb)).sum();
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << solve(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the performance might drop here but if you want more readable code, this might be better.